# WordPress insert_attachment set post_author

Tags: wordpress, upload, attachment

I want to post attachments from the front end in WordPress, here is my code which works:

**Form process:**

```
global $post;

if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );

            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $newupload = insert_attachment($file,0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Function to process uploads:**

```
function insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {
    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

    if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
    return $attach_id;
}
```

I would like to set the `post_author` of the attachment, as currently is defaults to the current logged in user.

I have tried adding the following into the function, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$my_post = array(
    'ID'          => $attach_id,
    'post_author' => 2
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what had happened, i retried this and seemed to of worked! Just wanted to update incase anyone else has the same issue!

```
   $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $attach_id,
      'post_author' => 2
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($setthumb) {
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
}
```

Well according to wp_update_post([codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post)) you have to pass the `POST_ID` and I am not sure if your `$attach_id` is the post ID, according to `update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);` Pass the `$post_id`

```
$my_post = array(
  'ID' => $post_id,
  'post_author' => 2
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Comment: Originally i did pass the $post_id, but this duplicated the page i was posting from, and didnt change the $attachment author in anyway